# Will this script lead to remote host filesystem read-only?

Tags: linux, ssh

Today, I'm trying to update the code on remote host with the script below.
As my local internet condition wasn't good, I installed the `screen` software, in case of disconnection.
And then I executed the script above. Things goes well for the first several app servers.
But when it goes to the last master server. I got an error about supervisor.
Then after debug, I found the whole file system on the master server suddenly became read-only.
I restarted it through ssh but can't connect to it anymore.
Is there a possibility that my operation of execute the script below leeds to this filesystem read-only disaster?
I'm so sacred now, because the $$$ of the company is evaporating at this moment.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` <tag or branch>"
    exit 1
fi

TAG=$1

WORK_DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)
GIT_REPO_PATH="/data/repo/backend_english"
APP_SRV_LIST="${WORK_DIR}/app_prd_srv.txt"

# Read the Destination directory
_DES_DIR="backend_english"
DES_FULL_DIR=''

read -p "Please Select the destination directory: [$_DES_DIR] " DES_DIR
if [ "x${DES_DIR}" != "x" ]; then
    DES_FULL_DIR="/data/sites/${DES_DIR}/"
fi


if [ ! -d "$DES_FULL_DIR" ]; then
    echo "Selecting default: /data/sites/${_DES_DIR}/"
    DES_FULL_DIR="/data/sites/${_DES_DIR}/"
else
    echo "destination dir: ${DES_FULL_DIR}"
fi

HOST=(`cat ${APP_SRV_LIST} | grep -v '^#' `)

echo "Deploy to the hosts:"
for i in ${HOST[@]}
do
    echo $i
done

read -p "Are you sure you want to continue (y/n)?" MFLAG
if [ "x${MFLAG}" != "xy" ]; then
    exit 1
fi


cd $GIT_REPO_PATH

/usr/bin/git fetch --all
/usr/bin/git checkout $TAG

THOST=${HOST[0]}

/usr/bin/rsync --dry-run -a --delete --progress --exclude='*.pyc' --exclude='upload_xls' --exclude='.git' --exclude='.gitignore' --exclude='logs' --exclude='test/local_config.py' $GIT_REPO_PATH/ admin@$THOST:$DES_FULL_DIR/

read -p "Are you sure you want to continue (y/n)?" CFLAG
if [ "x${CFLAG}" != "xy" ]; then
    exit 1
fi

echo $TAG > $WORK_DIR/version_prd.txt

for host in ${HOST[@]}
do
    echo $host

    rsync -a --delete --progress --exclude='upload_xls' --exclude='.git' --exclude='.gitignore' --exclude='logs' --exclude='test/local_config.py' $GIT_REPO_PATH/ admin@$host:$DES_FULL_DIR/

done

echo " "
echo " "

read -p "Restart all process (y/n)?" RFLAG
if [ "x${RFLAG}" != "xy" ]; then
    exit 0
fi

for host in ${HOST[@]}
do
    echo $host
    ssh admin@$host /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl -u my_account -p my_password restart all
done
```

Comment: Seems likely that the final server had an issue that prevented your script running because it was already read-only - and it probably got that way through a disk issue of some kind, and it is now unable to boot.  Knowing the error you got, and exactly what step in the script it occurred would help, but ultimately, someone needs to go on site and fix it.

Comment: @Paul, I sshed to that host, supervisor error was caused by unable to write temp files. And it turns out all filesystem was read-only.

Comment: Yes, so it was already read-only no doubt.  As you have restarted it and cannot connect, you won't be able to determine what is the problem until someone goes on site.  But it is very unlikely this has anything to do with your script.  It may well be sitting there after an fsck waiting for someone to press the 'y' button to complete the fix.

Comment: @Paul, I got this reply from the IDC "We were able to login and ran the file system check on the server which fixed several orphaned inode files.". Why orphaned inode will leads to a whole read-only filesystem?

Comment: Orphaned inodes do not directly cause a file-system to go read-only. A broken disk or filesystem causes a file system to go read only, a broken filesystem also causes orphaned inodes. You're confusing correlation with causality.